# Nowrap for the HTML table caption

Tags: html, css

I am creating an html table using VBA and everything works fine except the table caption that gets a line break. I am trying to make it no-wrap, but it is not working, where do I make a mistake?

`<Caption style="white-space: nowrap"> MyTable </Caption>`

I applied the same styling to `<td>` tags too, but the result is the same. It seems that caption is bound to the first column's width, how can I make caption to be shown in one line only regardless of the columns width?

Comment: Hi, Billy Mays here, [Kaboom](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_nowrap.asp) baby!

Comment: The `<td>` nowrap attribute isn't supported in HTML5, so you need to use inline styles like above.

Comment: If you read the page, a sentence highlighted in red it shows the correct way.

Comment: Oh and, don't use `<caption>` in a `<td>` element. td stands for table data. Does a caption belong in there? No, atmost a `<span>` as it does as its  inheritance is minimalistic.

Comment: Guys, I just need to make the caption ONE LINE. I explained what I tried and I cannot use CSS file or so. I have to do an inline styling using `style="Bluh bluh bluh..."` in the `<caption>` tag. I still cannot get what your solution is?

Comment: Oh atheism, please google [html caption](https://www.google.nl/search?q=html+captopm&gws_rd=cr&ei=uUkaWe-bG4XTwQLh6YrAAw#q=html+caption) ~> `The <caption> tag must be inserted immediately after the <table> tag.` so what has a `<td>` width has to do with anything? You're applying it wrong and if you didn't, how can we tell? You didn't add enough code for that.

Comment: @Xorifelse I am not applying any styling to `<td>` tags so as I explained, I was just trying to see if they have any effect on each othe or not. So the question remains very simple. How can I make the caption one line regardless of the other styling?

Comment: `I applied the same styling to <td> tags too,` ~> `I am not applying any styling to <td> tags so as I explained`... Please add your [mcve] table.

Comment: here is an example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFMWUMK3SQHL

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFMX4JZZ28W1, Define the outer container width. Its the inner elements defining the total width of the outer container. That includes default padding and margin.

Comment: The white-space: nowrap; should work fine. Could you show more code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the CSS property `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden;` in your `style` attribute. Run the snippet below to sure what it's working.

```html
<table>
  <caption style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">This is very very very long caption. The text is never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a &lt;br&gt; tag is encountered.</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>col 1</td>
      <td>col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```